# Need to reassign data, paginator, and sort on every new row in mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Ive got a `<mat-table>` where I've implemented an `addRow()` function that creates a new row in the table using a set of default values based on the data-type.

The issue that I'm having is that everytime I create a new row, I need to re-assign the `MatTableDataSource`, the `MatPaginator`, and the `MatSort`. If I don't perform the reassignments, then the new data doesn't show, or the pagination/sorting does not work.

All these reassignments seem expensive and roundabout, especially on larger datasets, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it better.

**dynamic-table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { TableField } from 'src/app/models/table-field';

const fields: TableField[] = [
  { name: "job", type: "string", editType: "free", options: [] },
  { name: "wage", type: "string", editType: "free", options: [] },
  { name: "state", type: "string", editType: "spinner", options: ["MI", "CA", "TX"] },
  { name: "isUnion", type: "boolean", editType: "checkbox", options: [] }
];

const rows: any[] = [
  { job: "J1", wage: "10.00", state: "MI", isUnion: false },
  { job: "J2", wage: "15.00", state: "TX", isUnion: true },
  { job: "J3", wage: "77.00", state: "CA", isUnion: true }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-table',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-table.component.css']
})
export class DynamicTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  Fields: {}[];
  Rows: {}[];
  ColumnHeaders: string[];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<{}>;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Fields = fields.map(field => field);
    this.ColumnHeaders = this.Fields.map(field => field["name"]);
    this.Rows = rows.map(row => row);
    console.log(this.Fields);
    console.log(this.Rows);
    console.log(this.ColumnHeaders);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(rows);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  addRow() {
    let row = {};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      switch(field.editType) { 
        case "free": { 
           row[field.name] = "default"
           break; 
        } 
        case "spinner": { 
           row[field.name] = field.options[0]; 
           break; 
        }
        case "checkbox": { 
          row[field.name] = false;
          break; 
       }
      } 
    });
    this.Rows = this.Rows.concat(row);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Rows);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  printRows() {
    console.log(this.dataSource.data)
  }
}
```

**dynamic-table.component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of Fields" matColumnDef="{{field.name}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{field.name}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <input *ngIf="field.editType == 'free'" matInput [(ngModel)]="row[field.name]" placeholder="{{row[field.name]}}" required>
            <mat-select *ngIf="field.editType == 'spinner'" [(ngModel)]="row[field.name]">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of field.options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-checkbox *ngIf="field.editType == 'checkbox'" [(ngModel)]="row[field.name]">
            </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ColumnHeaders"></tr>x
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ColumnHeaders;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
<button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<button mat-button color="primary" (click)="printRows()">Print Rows</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setters for pagination and sort components

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false })
  set paginator(value: MatPaginator) {
    if(this.dataSource) {
      this.dataSource.paginator = value;
    }
  }
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) 
  set sort(value: MatSort) {
    if(this.dataSource) {
      this.dataSource.sort = value;
    }
  }
```

You can remove the assignation here:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    //this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

To modify the table you have no choice but to reassign the data source.
When you will add a new row, just modify the datasource. Thanks to the setters, the paginator and sort component will be updated.

```
  addRow() {
    let row = {};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      switch(field.editType) { 
        case "free": { 
           row[field.name] = "default"
           break; 
        } 
        case "spinner": { 
           row[field.name] = field.options[0]; 
           break; 
        }
        case "checkbox": { 
          row[field.name] = false;
          break; 
       }
      } 
    });
    this.Rows = this.Rows.concat(row);
    this.dataSource.data = this.Rows;
  }
```

Comment: As someone newer to TS/JS, is the assignment to MatTableDataSource by reference? I expect this table to hold thousands of rows once we go live, so a re-assignment of all the data on every new row sounds like a potential issue.

Comment: You can do the test with 15,000 entries for example, you won't have any performance issues.
The reassignment of the DataSource for static data is described in the official documentation of angular material.
But if you use an external data source, I advise you to use the connect() method of MatDataSource, it's explained in the outline here: 
https://medium.com/@jchavez1894/tables-with-dynamic-data-using-angular-and-material-4dbbfa552083

Comment: Thanks for the additional link. the static data was just for a POC, and I will be updating to extract from a live/external source.